# Interrupting dbplyr Queries to (SQLite) Databases in R

Tags: r, database, sqlite, dplyr, dbplyr

In R(Studio), when sending `d(b)plyr` queries off to databases, is there any way to interrupt the query in case you made a mistake building your query or in case the query takes too long?

Interrupting in-memory `dplyr` operations is easy either through mashing `Esc`, or mashing the interrupt button in the RStudio GUI.

I put SQLite in brackets for my question as it is the primary database type I'm working with, I'm not sure this problem is applicable to all database types.

The [SQLite documentation](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/interrupt.html) says that by hitting `Ctrl+C` would be able to interrupt the query, but that does not work in the R console. Again, I'm not sure if this is solely a problem with `dbplyr` and SQLite, or if this applies to other databases.

It also doesn't work by hitting `Esc`, or mashing the interrupt (Stop Sign) button in RStudio.

For now, if it's a big query, I have to wait for the entire thing to run or hit an error to stop.

I'm not including a reprex as I don't think this question warrants it, as it's a bit more of a user-interface-type question. However, if a reprex is needed, I'll provide one.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I've run into the same thing and have been unable to find a way to interrupt. Often the holdup is in the C-level of things, so interrupts do not always break through.